# Creating HTML table in R shiny

Tags: html, css, shiny

Below is the table created in Notepad (using HTML). I need to replicate the same in R shiny using tags feature. I know we can populate this table without tags in R shiny. But may I please know how do we create this table using html tags in R shiny? I mean like below in sample. HTML and CSS experts anyone can help me here?

sample

```
tags$table(tags$thead("Head", tags$tr.........)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the HTML code that made that table, I've reproduced it myself:

```
<table border = "5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" height = "100" width = "800">TABLE TITLE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <style>
        tr:nth-child(1) { border: solid thick; }
        </style>
      <td align = "center"><strong>Column A</strong></td>
      <td align = "center"><strong>Column B</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: solid thick">
      <td align = "center"><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
      <td align = "center"><strong>Data 2</strong></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now you can pretty much directly translate this into R code following the flow of the HTML, ignoring style tags, which will be placed in one function call.

```r
  tags$head(tags$table(border = 5, 
                       tags$thead(
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$th(colspan = 2, height = 100, width = 800, 
                                   align = "center", "TABLE TITLE")
                           )
                       ), 
                       tags$tbody(
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$td(align = "center", strong("Column A")),
                           tags$td(align = "center", strong("Column B"))
                         ),
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$td(align = "center", "Data 1"),
                           tags$td(align = "center", "Data 2")
                         )
                       )
  )
  )
```

Where `<` corresponds to `(` and likewise `</` corresponds to `)`. If a new tag is opened before the previous one is closed, i.e. `<` place a new `tags$...` inside the open `tags$...`. The final output is just HTML code anyway, so keep trying until the output matches the HTML you have.

However, it takes a fair bit of CSS to get to the final table, as it has additional styling. We use a single `tags$head(tags$style())` call to place all our CSS code in one place for readability.

```r
  tags$head(tags$style(

  'thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
  }

    tr:nth-child(1) {
      border: solid thick;
    }

    tr:nth-child(2) {
      border: solid thick;
    }

    th {
      text-align: center
      ;
      }

   td, th {
    outline: none;
   }

    table { 
      display: table;
      border-collapse: separate;
      white-space: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      font-family: times-new-roman;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: medium;
      font-style: normal;
      color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
      text-align: start;
      border-spacing: 2px;
      border-color: grey;
      font-variant: normal;
    }  

    td {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: inherit;
    }

    tr {
      display: table-row;
      vertical-align: inherit;
    }




  '

  ))
```

If you have the source code you are trying to replicate, you can use inspect element in your browser to get CSS code. If not, you will need some outside resources (like Stackoverflow, WS3 schools, JSfiddle etc) to get your final web app.

Putting it all together in one Shiny App:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(

  'thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
  }

    tr:nth-child(1) {
      border: solid thick;
    }

    tr:nth-child(2) {
      border: solid thick;
    }

    th {
      text-align: center
      ;
      }

   td, th {
    outline: none;
   }

    table { 
      display: table;
      border-collapse: separate;
      white-space: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      font-family: times-new-roman;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: medium;
      font-style: normal;
      color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
      text-align: start;
      border-spacing: 2px;
      border-color: grey;
      font-variant: normal;
    }  

    td {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: inherit;
    }

    tr {
      display: table-row;
      vertical-align: inherit;
    }




  '

  )),

  tags$head(tags$table(border = 5, 
                       tags$thead(
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$th(colspan = 2, height = 100, width = 800, 
                                   align = "center", "TABLE TITLE")
                           )
                       ), 
                       tags$tbody(
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$td(align = "center", strong("Column A")),
                           tags$td(align = "center", strong("Column B"))
                         ),
                         tags$tr(
                           tags$td(align = "center", "Data 1"),
                           tags$td(align = "center", "Data 2")
                         )
                       )
  )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Wow. First of all thanks a lot for your time . Really appreciate. Thanks a lot again

Comment: I voted. Also, wanted to know small thing. In HTML and css , is there a way to rename a column name? Example. I need to rename Column B as Category. I mean to say . Is there a code for that?

Comment: Since we are using html tags to create the table yes, just replace ````strong("Column B")```` with ````strong("Category")````.

Comment: Thanks . No no. Actually what I meant was, it should not be direct replace like u suggested. I meant , is there something like, strong(column B) = strong(category) . So basically, a conditional replacement. Make sense??

Comment: Since the html tag functions return a string of HTML code, you can use regex to search the list for <strong>Column B</strong> and replace that with <strong>Category</strong>

Comment: Like? How does it know to replace column B? Sorry I may be wrong.

Comment: Well in this case, there's only one column B. I suspect you might have multiple? In that case, make use of ```jQuery``` to find the specific column you want to rename.

Comment: Yeah. Your right. Multiple. Can u put an example please. I am not aware of jquery. Please

Comment: Can't do it here, ask a new question with sample code and data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268402/renaming-column-names-in-html. I have added here. Please help